# extract elements from a html page

Tags: html, xml, phantomjs, scrape

I download some youtube comment page and I want to extract username(or user display name)
and the link
like from the following code block:

```
 <p class="metadata">
      <span class="author ">
        <a href="/channel/UCuoJ_C5xNTrdnc4motXPHIA" class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-user-name " data-sessionlink="ei=CKG174zFqbQCFZmaIQodtmyE0A%3D%3D" dir="ltr">Sabil Muhammad</a>
      </span>
        <span class="time" dir="ltr">
          <a dir="ltr" href="http://www.youtube.com/comment?lc=S2ZH2gSPYaef43vTRkLDxUzo2fYicVUc3SFvmYq2jrs">
            il y a 1 jour
          </a>
        </span>
    </p>
```

I want to extract 
    /channel/UCuoJ_C5xNTrdnc4motXPHIA
and 
    Sabil Muhammad

there are of course many many lines in the html page, but I only want to focus on code blocks as the above and extract all usernames and corresponding links, and put them into a log file

are there any good scripts for this? 
I know bash and c/c++

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to accomplish something like this by iterating through all of the '`metadata`' classes and pulling the contents that you need :

```
//After including jQuery within your page
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Iterates through each of the metadata tags
    $('.metadata').each(function()
    {
          //Pulls the username
          var username = $('.yt-user-name', this).text();
          //Pulls the link
          var link = $('.time a', this).attr('href');
          //Process each accordingly
          alert(username + ':' + link);
    });
});
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AGNa6/3)**

Comment: besides, in each page there are many such code blocks and other lines, I want to get all the usernames and links on each page. And I want to automate scripts on many pages.

Comment: Hi wenzi, Sorry I had posted the wrong version of the demo. (It has been updated). This will work for as many of the links as there are on the page, as long as they are in the proper format. You could add more functionality based on whatever your needs were. However, if you are pulling these from Youtube, it's possible you could run into some cross-site issues that are common in scraping.

Comment: I just do it for research, BTW, you mean I need to insert the scripts into the html page? can I just run the scripts over the html pages and write the usernames and links into some log files?

Comment: You could just execute the script on the live page (via the console in your browser) and log the results in the console (then copy it to your text file)

Comment: console in my browser? what's that? I don't want browser to be involved, I just hope to run the javascript scripts like shell scripts, is it possible or not? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, it's quite easy. However, if you're doing it in bash or c/c++ you'll need to retrieve the content of the page and parse for the elements you are interested in. You could treat the elements as XML and parse for attributes fairly easily.

You could use regex, or simple text matching with sub strings.

Answer (score 0):

with awk(if you are good in bash) you can read the page line by line and put a filter to catch `<p class="metadata">` and start to copy and end copy if you face `</p>`

then work on that extracted part, and so on...