# is it possible to run jquery/javascript script independently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many html pages on my computer
and I want to write a javascript script to harvest those pages for some text/elements
(see [extract elements from a html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978021/extract-elements-from-a-html-page))
someone has write some jquery codes, which can extract the elements I want, but I don't know how to run the scripts over html pages on linux console and put the extracted elements into log files

so basically I want to run like:

```
javascript.js page1.html

javascript.js page2.html

javascript.js page3.html
```

besides, is it possible to use javascript to write to some files?
BTW, I'M on linux
thanks!

Comment: You can't use JavaScript to create files on your local machine, no. I'm afraid the rest of your question makes no sense to me.

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "harvest those pages for some text/elements"?

Comment: Checkout http://nodejs.org/

Comment: If you want to send me the jquery files and a few sample html files, I could take a crack at getting it to work using phantom.js. My email is in my profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a handful of ways to run Javascript at the command-line.

If you're on Windows, you can write `WSH`-style shell scripts in JS.  Done!

If you're on Mac/Linux, all you need is a command-line JS parser. I've tried a few and I like `V8` the best, though getting it compiled is a bit of a pain.

The part about using jQuery makes very little sense, though, because jQuery is primarily intended to provide shortcuts into the DOM of a web page.

So, if what you're really hoping to do is run a script against several HTML files, and query their DOMs, it might be time to look at `Webdriver`, although `Phantomjs` is probably a much easier place to start.

Comment: someone has write some jquery codes, which can extract the elements I want, but I don't know how to run the scripts over html pages on linux console and put the extracted elements into log files

Comment: In that case, start by looking into `phantomjs`.  It should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)? This is a framework that allows you to write server-side javascript, and there are libraries for reading from and writing to disk.

However, you should be aware that Node.js isn't a browser, so you won't get access to the DOM (because there's no document). In place of `window`, you get `process`, which holds properties like where you are in the file system.

If you need access to the DOM, you might want to look into [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/).

Comment: my requirements are in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978021/extract-elements-from-a-html-page, and the html pages are from youtube comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to write to the file system if you use the right framework, such as nodejs or phantomjs.  I don't quite understand the first part of your question, but if you are wanting to scrape a web page then phantomjs is a very good choice.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows machines you can run JS files via WScript.exe, e.g.

WScript.exe javascript.js "page1.html"